# weighted integral convergence

Tags: integration

Let $U$ be a bounded open set of $\mathbb{R}^N$, and $f_n:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of positive Lebesgue-measurable functions such that $\int_U f_n  \to 1$.

Let $b:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $0<b<1$ in $U$.

Can we have $\int_U bf_n  \to 1$ ?

Comment: take $b$ to be equal to $1/2$ on $U$ , clearly the limit is not 1

Comment: But you picked a particular . Let me put it in another way: is it true that for any such sequence  and any such  we have $\lim \int_U bf_n \neq 1$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we have such examples. Let $U=(0,1)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $f_n(x)=(n-1)\chi_{(0,1/n)}(x) + 1/(n-1) \  \chi_{(1/n,1)}(x)$, and $b(x)=1/(1+x^2)$. Then we have

$$
\int_U f_n = 1 \ \textrm{ for all }n\ge 2. 
$$

Moreover,
$$\begin{align}
\int_U bf_n &= \int_0^{1/n} \frac {n-1}{1+x^2} dx+O\left(\frac1{n-1}\right)\\
&= (n-1) \tan^{-1}(1/n) +O\left(\frac1{n-1}\right)\\
&\rightarrow 1  \ \textrm{ as } n\rightarrow\infty.\end{align}
$$